# while accessing a site hosted in the staging environment getting access forbidden error

Tags: google-chrome

When i try to open a particular URL in the staging environment am getting 403 Access Forbidden in Chrome (tried IE, Firefox as well ). The same site is opening to the person sitting next to me. 
both are connected to same network, tried clearing cookies , tried opening from different browsers .

Anything that i should be looking in particular, in this scenario ?

Comment: Virtually all 4xx HTTP error codes indicate that the user/requester is at fault. Specifically the 403 error is telling you exactly what's going on: the server and/or router is preventing you from reaching that site. It may be that you're using an incorrect port number, but without specific details, I don't believe anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: What specific details you need ? pls let me know. Also am not using any ports to access the site , its a direct URL which is hosted in our staging environment.

Comment: Specifically, some of the details you mentioned in your last comment, but more completely: You're trying to access a server that you have control over (instead of a some arbitrary server whose configuration is unknown to you, which isn't clear in the question). Please look at and provide details of that web server's configuration. It may be the case that the webserver is configured to accept requests only across a specific port (e.g., https://foobar.com:8888). Additionally, which browsers have your and your colleague tried? Without detailed information, all I or anyone can do is speculate.

Comment: so we're accessing the site something like this https://stage1.xxx.xx/xx/en/home.page . now this is the same way my colleague  tried , he has tried it from IE,firefox,Chrome . Whenever i try from any of these sites am getting 403 access forbidden . Server side , i dont have control but if there is anything specifically needs to check i can have someone from other teams to check in server . But i dont know exactly what to look for.

Comment: Interestingly am able to connect to anothr url which is hotsed under the same server https://stage1.xxx.xx/en/registration/personal

Comment: OKie , Am able to find the issue. Antivirus was blocking me , disabled and working as expected.